# Looking for package in user dir fails

Tags: asp.net, nuget, teamcity, dnx

I'm trying to build a ASP.NET Core project with TeamCity using the plugin from JetBrains (https://github.com/JetBrains/teamcity-dotnet-plugin).

I've installed the plugin and I'm trying to build my project with the .NET Core (dotnet) runner. It's failing right away because it's looking for a dll from a package in my users directory.

```
[09:04:13][Step 2/2] Starting: "C:\Program Files\dotnet\bin\dotnet.exe" build LevApi
[09:04:13][Step 2/2] in directory: E:\TeamCity\buildAgent4\work\b62b6825dfad2144
[09:04:14][Step 2/2] Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.Numerics.Vectors\4.1.1-beta-23516\lib\portable-net45+win8\System.Numerics.Vectors.dll'.
[09:04:14][Step 2/2] Process exited with code 1
[09:04:14][Step 2/2] Step Build LevApi (.NET Core (dotnet)) failed
```

This is build with a build agent running under Local System account. I have another build agent running under my account, when I use that it's trying to find the dll in my users directory.

```
[Step 2/2] Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\dfpsb\.nuget\packages\System.Numerics.Vectors\4.1.1-beta-23516\lib\portable-net45+win8\System.Numerics.Vectors.dll'.
```

I can build other non-Core .NET projects just fine.
I'm at a loss if the problem is with NuGet 3.4.3, the ASP.NET Core installation or the plugin.

I'm using the latest runtime:

```
C:\Windows\system32>dnvm list

Active Version           Runtime Architecture Location                                                                            Alias
------ -------           ------- ------------ --------                                                                            -----
  *    1.0.0-rc1-update2 clr     x86          C:\Users\dfpsb\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update2\bin\dnx.exe\runtimes default
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out with the help from Dmitry who made the TC plugin.

I now execute a `dotnet restore` in a command line build step before building.